# Create a filtered list from another sorted list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of . I want to sort this list based on an Id property and then filter items based on a JoinedDate property. How do I use Linq here.

```
public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime JoinedDate { get; set; }

    }


static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            List<Person> persons = new List<Person> ();

            var date1 = new DateTime (2021, 1, 1);
            var date2 = new DateTime (2021, 2, 1);
            var date3 = new DateTime (2021, 3, 1);
            var date4 = new DateTime (2021, 4, 1);


            persons.Add(new Person {Id = 1, JoinedDate = date1, Name = "John"});
            persons.Add (new Person { Id = 2, JoinedDate = date2, Name = "Tim" });
            persons.Add (new Person  { Id = 3, JoinedDate = date3, Name = "Karl" });
            persons.Add (new Person { Id = 4, JoinedDate = date4, Name = "Jim" });

            // I have Two dates
            // From and To
            // Need to Created a list of person whose JoinedDate is between From and To data

            List<Person> filteredPersons = new List<Person> ();



        }
```

Comment: `persons.Where(x => x.JoinedDate > ... && x.JoinedDate < ...).OrderBy(y => y.Id)`?

Answer (score 2):

```
var filteredPersons = persons
                        .Where(person => 
                            person.JoinedDate >= from && person.JoinedDate <= to)
                        .OrderBy(person => person.Id)
                        .ToList();
```

Is all you need, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, as advised by @Crowcoder

```
persons.Where(person=>person.JoinedDate > new DateTime(year,month,day) && person.JoinedDate < new DateTime(year, month, day)).OrderBy(person=>person.Id).ToList()
```

PS. For clarity purposes, please rename your list to **people**.

Comment: That does not do a "between" comparison